# Obscure a UITextField password

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, security, ipad

I am doing a login page. I have UITextField for password.

Obviously, I do not want the password to be seen; instead, I want circles to show when typing.
How do you set the field for this to happen?

Answer (score 334, accepted):

Please set your UItextField property secure..

Try this..

```
textFieldSecure.secureTextEntry = true
```

textFieldSecure is your UITextField...

For newer Swift version, it is `textFieldSecure.isSecureTextEntry = true`

Comment: It has been changed to isSecureTextEntry in the new swift versions

Answer (score 82):

One can do this for Obscure a UITextField password:

[image]

**CODE**

**Objective-C:**

```
textField.secureTextEntry = YES;
```

**Swift:**

```
textField.isSecureTextEntry = true
```

Answer (score 37):

In Interface Builder check the "Secure Text Entry" checkbox

or

In code set:

**Objective-C:**

```
yourTextField.secureTextEntry = YES;
```

**Swift:**

```
yourTextField.secureTextEntry = true
```

Answer (score 11):

Set the `secureTextEntry` property to `YES`.

Answer (score 8):

Open the Xib file and open the inspector of the password text field and tick the secure property.

Answer (score 6):

**For Swift 3.0:**

```
txtpassword.isSecureTextEntry = true
```

Comment: Why are you just repeating the previous answers

Comment: where u see the ans.

Answer (score 4):

**in Swift 3.0 or later**

```
passwordTextField.isSecureTextEntry = true
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply check `Secure Text Entry` check box on the storyboard

[image]

Comment: Is there a way that I can even hide the character to be displayed at all? I don't want the character to be seen at all.

Comment: @ManinderSingh Sure but that requires some thinking out of the box. The idea I can think of is to use the text field delegate method to intercept all the inputs. After that return false to any intercepted characters and construct your string by yourself. Take a look at this delegate method `textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String)`

Answer (score 2):

```
txt_Password = new UITextField {
  Frame = new RectangleF (20,40,180,31),
  BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.Bezel,
  TextColor = UIColor.Black,
  SecureTextEntry = true,
  Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize (17f),
  Placeholder = "Enter Password",
  BackgroundColor = UIColor.White,
  AutocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.No,
  KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.Default,
  ReturnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done,
  ClearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.WhileEditing,
};
```

secureTextEntry set true.