# iPhone: can I have a hidden UITextField where the text is hidden with little circles

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make uitextfield password obscured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578824/make-uitextfield-password-obscured)

I have a app that takes in a pssword.  On the web a edit box can hide the text and just show little circles representing each letter, so some one else does not see the password.

Is thiere a way to do this on the iPhone?  I looked at apples documentation 
https://www.google.com/search?q=UITextField&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

for UITextField, did not find anything about hidding the text

Comment: There are several question related to this. You could have searched well before asking frequently asked question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the Secure checkbox is down the bottom in the Inspector:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
textField.secureTextEntry = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
UITextField *textField;

textField.secureTextEntry = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are building the App in Xcode you can just select the text field then check "Secure" in the Attributes Inspector.

or in code:

```
[self.passwordTextField setSecureTextEntry:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a secure text field.

```
textField.secureTextEntry = YES;
```