# Reveal Passcode dots using Swift

Tags: swift, ios8, swift2, ios9

How do I reveal the passcode dots in swift,  so then the user can see their password by clicking a button.
Thanks
Tyge

Answer (score 2):

TextField has a property called  secureTextEntry. All you need is to connect an outlet to your textfield and toggle secureTextEntry:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        passwordField.secureTextEntry = true
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func showHide(sender: UIButton) {
        passwordField.secureTextEntry = !passwordField.secureTextEntry
        sender.setTitle({passwordField.secureTextEntry ? "Show":"Hide"}(), forState: .Normal)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

stackoverflow provides a working search engine, but anyway here you is the answer.

Do the same, but with `false` instead of `true`

[Obscure a UITextField password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578824/obscure-a-uitextfield-password)

By the way make sure that the user knows what he does when reveal the secure text.