# Codename One Textfield Password Constraint

Tags: ios, passwords, constraints, textfield, codenameone

I am adding a field final TextField Password = new TextField("", "Password", 20, TextField.PASSWORD);

When the user types the password you can see all the letters until the user TAB's off the field. I would like to see Asterisks while the user is typing, i.e. hide each letter or like some applications it lets you see the letter until you type the next letter.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Use `secureTextEntry` property of `UITextField`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Obscure a UITextField password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578824/obscure-a-uitextfield-password)

Answer (score 1):

This is just the Codename One simulator behavior, on devices this should behave as expected